# Regular expression for not accepting a series of Dots(.)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with Javascript wherein I accept a Filename which is sent through an URL.

I have written a Regex to omit special characters.

```
    isFileNameValid: function (value)
    {                                 
        return new RegExp("([\\\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\/])").test(value);
    }
```

But I have failed to find a way to combine this with a regular expression which does not accept a string which has consecutive dots.

Any help is appreciable.

Comment: It's unclear what you want with your attempt. You seem to allow anything as long as it contains those special character.

Comment: I have another function which upon returning true by this function shows a message box that filename is invalid

Comment: I mean we have no idea what you consider a valid filename with your current code.

Comment: I recommend to use regex literals instead of strings (if you don't need to include variable content into the regex pattern) -> your regex would be `    /([\:*?"<>|\/])/` and I've no glue if it's what you want to have

Comment: @nhahtdh I consider a filename valid if it does not contain any of the above listed characters and consecutive dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you want, because it seems like that is approving strings that contain one of those special characters (as opposed to stripping them out which you say you are doing).

But, if you want for this function to return false if your current regex is true and the string contains consecutive periods, you can use the following

`[\\\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\/]|\.{2,}`

if you want the opposite logic, this should do it

`[\\\:\*\?\"\<\>\|\/]|(?!.*(\.{2,}))`

I would highly recommend using a regex visualizer, like [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/38lNya2lfdh0wIbr) for this sort of thing - makes it much easier

Comment: `[^\.]{2,}` This only say there exists 2 non `.` character consecutive to each other, but it doesn't check that the string doesn't have 2 consecutive `.`.

Comment: right - `\.{2,}` does. the question wasn't clear, so I listed both.

Comment: `[^\.]{2,}` is not the opposite of "not having `\.{2,}`"

Comment: This is still insufficient, since the check can succeed at the end of the string. The negative look-ahead should be anchored to beginning of the string. Anyway, the requirement is too unclear to suggest any improvement to the regex.

Comment: @Patrick Your solution also prohibits '2' from being in the string.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would just add another regex to the test function like

```js
isFileNameValid: function (value)
{                                 
    return  /([:*?"<>|\/])/.test(value) && !/[.]{2}/.test(value);
}
```

As stated in the comment above - I don't think `/([:*?"<>|\/])/` is correct anyways. With that, you simply test if **one of** the characters `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, `|`, or `/` is in `value` and if so, it's a valid filename?!